# Gradient vector of a function under transformation

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors

The following question from Griffiths Electromagnetism states :
Suppose that f is a function of two variables (y and z) only.
Show that the gradient ∇ f = (∂f/∂y)y + (∂f/∂z)z transforms as a vector under rotation.
Now I was able to solve this question using the Chain rule for partial derivatives and basic 2D vector transformations.
Basically I followed the exact process as given in the solution manual attached below , but not I am confused whether the gradient I have obtained has its unit vectors defined as the transformed axes or they are the original axes.
My guess is that they are probably the transformed axes as it does not make sense for the gradient to change with respect to the original axes.
If someone can provide me with some Mathematical or Intuitive reason as to why my reasoning is correct or incorrect, I would be grateful.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a rotation of coordinates, the components of the old system are projected onto the new rotated basis so that the new coordinates are the degree to which the old vector's components lie along the new direction of the rotated coordinates. Thus, such transformations are linear and are expressed in terms of the rotated basis.